# Range query in elasticsearch does not work properly

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index that contains objects eventvalue-eventtime. I want to write a query that will return aggregated event count based on eventvalue for the last 30 seconds. Also, I need empty buckets if for a given seconds there was no events - I need to display this data on a graph.

So I wrote the following query:

```
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "range" : { 
                        "eventtime" : {
                            "gte" : "now-30s/s",
                            "lte" : "now/s",
                            "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                            "time_zone": "+03:00"
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "range" : { 
                        "eventvalue" : {
                            "lte" : 3
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "aggs": {
        "values_agg": {
            "terms": {
                "field": "eventvalue",
                "min_doc_count" : 0,
                "order": {
                    "_term": "asc"
                }
            },
            "aggs": {
                "events_over_time" : {
                    "date_histogram" : {
                        "field" : "eventtime",
                        "interval" : "1s",
                        "min_doc_count" : 0,
                        "extended_bounds" : {
                            "min" : "now-30s/s",
                            "max" : "now/s"
                        },
                        "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
                        "time_zone": "+03:00"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This query is not working properly and I don't know why. Specifically, the first "range" query gives me desired interval (if I remove it I'm getting values from all time). But the second "range" query seems to have no effect. Eventvalue can be anywhere from 1 to 10 and the desired effect is that I will have three buckets for eventvalues 1-3. However, I get all 10 buckets with all events.

How can I fix this query so it still returns empty buckets but only for selected evenvalues?

Comment: Can you check the mapping for `eventvalue` and let us know what it is set to? (`string`, `long` or `double`)

Comment: @Weinberger eventvalue is integer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to remove the `"min_doc_count": 0` from your `terms` aggregation. To achieve the empty buckets you're aiming for, you need only use `min_doc_count` in the `date_histogram` aggregation.

Per the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_minimum_document_count_3) for the terms aggregation:

> Setting min_doc_count=0 will also return buckets for terms that didn’t
>   match any hit.

This explains why you are seeing buckets for *eventvalue*s that are greater than 3. They were filtered out by the query, but brought back in by the terms aggregation.

**UPDATE**

Since there is a possibility that the *eventvalues* may not exist anywhere in the 30sec time slice, the other approach I would recommend is to manually specify the discrete values you want to use as buckets using a `filters` aggregation. See the [documentation here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/search-aggregations-bucket-filters-aggregation.html).

Try using this for your aggregations:

```
"aggs": {
  "values_agg": {
    "filters": {
      "filters": {
        "1": { "term": { "eventvalue": 1 }},
        "2": { "term": { "eventvalue": 2 }},
        "3": { "term": { "eventvalue": 3 }}
      }
    },
    "aggs": {
      "events_over_time" : {
        "date_histogram" : {
          "field" : "eventtime",
          "interval" : "1s",
          "min_doc_count" : 0,
          "extended_bounds" : {
            "min" : "now-30s/s",
            "max" : "now/s"
          },
          "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
          "time_zone": "+03:00"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't remove it. I tried. I get completely empty results then.

Comment: Can you update your question and provide some sample documents? I created a test index using my best guess of how your documents were structured and I was able to get the results you are looking for.

Comment: Also, what version of ES are you using?

Comment: I just realized that my answer only works as long as every eventvalue occurs *at least once* in the 30sec time frame. If that is not the case for your data, then I understand why you are getting empty results for certain eventvalues.

Comment: @Alex Have a look at my updated answer. Using a `filters` aggregation is the only way I see to essentially plug in terms for ES to aggregate on that don't exist in your documents. Histograms do this by default, but in my testing, if you use multiple nested histograms with `min_doc_count` = 0, you still end up with empty buckets.

Comment: thanks for your input filters are seem to be working. A little less generic result since as far as I understand, filters accept only specific values and not intervals, so I need to know exact name of the bucket, not just go though them and see the `eventvalue` inside.
P.S. I use the most recent ES available, 2.1 I suppose.